# SQL update multiple columns matching a pattern

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a table in a postgresql database in which I have multiple columns matching a pattern `/\w*(?:_open|_close)/g`.
Those are timefields.

I would like to substract 1 hour from all the rows on those columns. Is there a way to do without running an UPDATE query separately for each column?

Comment: You don't need to run multiple updates, you can update more than one column in a single update.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-update.html

Comment: I formulated my question bad. What I meant was of course not to have to repeat the pattern in the query (or just write multiple queries if you like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to avoid writing:

```
  UPDATE mytable SET
   door_open = door_open + INTERVAL '1' HOUR,
   door_close = door_close + INTERVAL '1' HOUR,
   car_open = car_open + INTERVAL '1' HOUR,
   car_close = car_close + INTERVAL '1' HOUR,
   ... blah blah ...
  WHERE
   ...
```

and instead want a way to match column names by wildcard.

If that is the case, then no, there is no built-in way to do that.

You can construct a query dynamically using PL/PgSQL: Use a query against the `information_schema.columns` view to get column names, then string concatenation to form the query. Then you can run it with `EXECUTE`. There are many examples of such dynamic SQL elsewhere on Stack Overflow.

e.g.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  sqlstring text;
BEGIN
  SELECT INTO sqlstring
   'UPDATE blah SET '
   || string_agg(format('%I = %I + INTERVAL ''1'' HOUR', column_name, column_name), ', ') 
   || ' WHERE true'
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_name = 'blah'
    AND table_schema = 'public';

  EXECUTE sqlstring;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, rather.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and added example. BTW, in a totally unrelated post (just deleted by poster, hence mentioning here) you wrote that MySQL ignores foreign keys. Not true since 5.0, it's like saying MySQL doesn't support transactions, PostgreSQL requires manual VACUUM to keep working, or PostgreSQL doesn't support replication. Separately to that, using MyISAM should require starting MySQL with a "--eat-my-data-please-I-want-to-use-myisam" flag, but ....

Comment: I wrote  "MySQL ignores ***inline*** foreign key constraints"  which is still true with 5.6: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc801/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah. Important word there. Gotcha. Also ugh.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, CraigRinger: parses for correctness and then ignores (doesn't even check if the referenced table or column exist or if the number of columns or types match): [sqlfiddle-ulala](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40a6a)